# NPError: npm - Could not resolve dependency

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm getting an error while trying to "npm install" some packages.

Below is the log trace.

```
# npm resolution error report

2021-11-24T10:58:12.449Z

While resolving: minible-react@1.0.0
Found: react@17.0.2
node_modules/react
  react@"^17.0.2" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from availity-reactstrap-validation@2.7.1
node_modules/availity-reactstrap-validation
  availity-reactstrap-validation@"^2.7.1" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Raw JSON explanation object:

```
{
"code": "ERESOLVE",
"current": {
"name": "react",
"version": "17.0.2",
"whileInstalling": {
  "name": "minible-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "path": "/Users/ranj/Desktop/Minible_React_v2.2.0/Admin"
},
"location": "node_modules/react",
"isWorkspace": false,
"dependents": [
  {
    "type": "prod",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "^17.0.2",
    "from": {
      "location": "/Users/ranj/Desktop/Minible_React_v2.2.0/Admin"
    }
  }
]
},
"currentEdge": {
"type": "prod",
"name": "react",
"spec": "^17.0.2",
"from": {
  "location": "/Users/ranj/Desktop/Minible_React_v2.2.0/Admin"
}
},
"edge": {
"type": "peer",
"name": "react",
"spec": "^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0",
"error": "INVALID",
"from": {
  "name": "availity-reactstrap-validation",
  "version": "2.7.1",
  "whileInstalling": {
    "name": "minible-react",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "path": "/Users/ranj/Desktop/Minible_React_v2.2.0/Admin"
  },
  "location": "node_modules/availity-reactstrap-validation",
  "isWorkspace": false,
  "dependents": [
    {
      "type": "prod",
      "name": "availity-reactstrap-validation",
      "spec": "^2.7.1",
      "from": {
        "location": "/Users/ranj/Desktop/Minible_React_v2.2.0/Admin"
      }
    }
  ]
}
},
"strictPeerDeps": false,
"force": false
}
```

Comment: try npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 2):

you can try using command with --force :

```
npm install --force @your-npm-package
```

or

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: npm install --legacy-peer-deps did the trick. Thank you

Comment: While this may get around the issue temporarily, this hides the underlying problem